# Xcode 10 GM seed: NS_OPTIONS (objc export of options) no longer compiles

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, ServiceType) {
 foo = 1 << 0,
 bar = 1 << 1,
 AllServices = 0x3
};
```

now yields in baz.swift:136:15: Enum case 'foo' not found in type 'ServiceType?'

What I'm doing newly wrong here?
This worked in xcode 9.4.1

The cases where it does not work:

key to a dictionary:

[ServiceType.foo.rawValue: somevalue, ....

this:
[.foo.rawValue: somevalue, ....

works in 9.4.1 (but not in 10)

Oh, in cases where ServiceType is force unwrapped var to a enum

```
let s: ServiceType!
....
switch(s)
{
case ServiceType.foo:
```

compiles (and compact notation does not)
this:

```
let s: ServiceType
....
switch(s)
{
case .foo:
```

compiles fine as expected

Comment: Where do you put that code? How is it imported to Swift? Which exact line causes the error message?

Comment: I found the answer in xocde 10 you have to do ServiceType.foo instead of the .foo notation of the yesteryear

Comment: I doubt that this changed between Xcode/Swift versions. `.foo` is sufficient if the type can be inferred from the context. Also `'ServiceType?'` indicates that there might be optionals involved. –  Please show the code which compiles in Xcode 9, but not in Xcode 10!

Comment: Aren't you using an older version of Xcode 10 beta? I remember such behavior in some betas, but not in Xcode 10 GM seed.

Comment: no, it's the freshly installed gm seed

Comment: Version 10.0 (10A254a)

Comment: Then the similar bug I have found in some older beta may still exist in some other contexts. But you should better show more context to reproduce your issue. In all cases I have tested, the dot-leaded notation `.foo` works as expected. Please show how you get that error.

Comment: Yes, sometime .foo works, most of the times it does not without specifying the context. In switch cases for example. Not the best use of options but sometimes it's a valid usecase

Comment: As far as I tested (and in all my experiences using Xcode 9), the dictionary key case using `.rawValue` dose NOT compile in Xcode 9.4.1. And the second example switch-case, it's rather a [problem of implicitly unwrapped Optional](https://swift.org/blog/iuo/) than NS_OPTIONS.

Answer (score -3):

Apparently in xcode 10 in some cases you have to do the longish ServiceType.foo instead of the compact .foo notation of the yesteryear